# AppWidgetProvider problem

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, alarmmanager, android-appwidget

I have an AppWidgetProvider, and I need to do some initialization when a widget is first added to the home screen. I understand that the place to do it is in the onEnabled(Context context) method. My Problem is that this method is never called (As far as I can see in the logcat).

Here is my code:

```
public class MyMonitorWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);

        Log.v("LOG", "Widget onEnabled");
        Intent intentToFire = new Intent(UpdateAlarmReceiver.ACTION_UPDATE_ALARM); 
        context.sendBroadcast(intentToFire);
    } 
...
}
```

And my appwidget-provider xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
  android:minWidth="146dp" 
  android:minHeight="74dp"
  android:label="Monitor Widget"
  />
```

and in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="MyMonitorWidget" android:label="Monitor Widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.myMonitor.ACTION_NOTIFY_WIDGET"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" 
        android:resource="@xml/monitor_widget_info"/>
    </receiver>
```

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: CommonsWare's answer is correct, but if you have played around with faulty code, you probably will have to uninstall the app before it starts to working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED` as another action:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Without that, you will not receive the broadcast that triggers `onEnabled()`.

Comment: Thanks man... But it seems that onEnabled is still not being called. I also experimented with APPWIDGET_DELETED but it doesn't work either... What am I missing?

Comment: @Alex1987: AFAIK, that should have been sufficient.

Comment: It suddenly works.. I don't know what has happened but it works... Thanks man :)

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget about `android:exported` property! I didn't receive `onDelete()` when `android:exported` was `false`

```
<receiver 
    ...
    android:exported="true"
    ... >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED" />
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data 
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource=... />
</receiver>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I just lost some good hours trying to understand why I did not get notified when my last widget got removed...