# Android: is APPWIDGET_ENABLED necessary in the Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

So, until now I've been merrily overriding `onEnabled()` in my `AppWidgetProvider`, though calling `super()` too, in order to do some stuff when the first widget is placed (e.g. after a reboot... like setting repeating alarms up again for all widgets).

It's been working just fine, apparently.  I'm also overriding `onReceive()` so that I can catch certain other broadcasts, and in there I can log what broadcasts I'm receiving, and one of those is `APPWIDGET_ENABLED`, which is dispatched to `onEnabled()` as I understand.

So, all is good.  But...

On examining my `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I notice that I have some actions registered in my `<intent-filter>`, e.g.:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
    ... (others) ...
</intent-filter>
```

BUT a glaring omission is the following:

```
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
```

I do **not** have the above in my Manifest (at present).

So, is it actually necessary to register the `APPWIDGET_ENABLED` in the Manifest?  Posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6815359/4070848) suggest that it is.  On the other hand, I'm sure I've read somewhere that this action is automatically received.  And indeed my `onReceive()` method is logging that it is being received by my `AppWidgetProvider` despite not being in the Manifest.

Perhaps the implementation might vary from Android version to version, or even device to device, so that on some devices `APPWIDGET_ENABLED` is received automatically and on others not?

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an widget , you need is AppWidgetProviderInfo object, which you will define in a separate widget XML file.At that time of creating widget only,you need to declare this in manifest xml file.

```
 <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"></action>
      </intent-filter>
```